# jQuery datepicker - how to detect the trigger element

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 4 elements (`<input>`'s) on my page which trigger jQuery UI datepickers.

How can I detect which element has fired the currently showing datepicker.

I want to do

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

using the `defaultDate` option. However my function cannot tell what to use for '.selector'

**Is there a way to get the triggering element for the current instance of the datepicker at any time?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside of the callback function, use `$(this)`.

Comment: what callback function is this?

Comment: Every event method accepts a callback function, that function will be called whenever the event occurs. Inside of the callback function, $(this) usually takes the form of the jQuery element that triggered the event (i.e. your datepicker).